# Ubuntu software centre is loading a blank window

Tags: software-center

This issue has reared its head just today. the Ubuntu Software Centre seems to be broken

It loads up a blank window with the title "Ubuntu Software Centre" but doesn't do anything else after that.

Here is the console output:

```
    rymate@rymate-Aspire-5551:~$ software-center
    2011-12-26 16:21:10,618 - softwarecenter.ui.gtk3.em - INFO - EM's: 17 15 21
    rymate@rymate-Aspire-5551:~$
```

Anything I can do to fix? Or am I gonna have to use synaptic package manager to install stuff.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! [What to do with questions that describe known bugs?](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1317/what-to-do-with-questions-that-describe-known-bugs/) this has been reported on [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-center/+bug/772549) and as such is now closed.